# How many combinations of size $n+1$ at least in a group of $2n$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations of size $n+1$ at least in a group of $2n$ elements ?

It seems that total amount of combinations is equal to $2^{2n}$ in this case, but what if I only want the number of combinations strictly bigger than n elements ?

Comment: See [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) and examine (for example) $$\sum_{k=3}^4 \binom{4}{k}, ~\sum_{k=4}^6 \binom{6}{k}, ~\sum_{k=5}^8 \binom{8}{k}, \cdots .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly poorly phrased question, but a pretty simple answer. We know
$$
{a\choose b} = {a\choose a-b}
$$

and so we have that
$$
{2n\choose x} = {2n\choose 2n-x}
$$

This gives us a nice symmetry in your 2n elements between the combinations of size less than $n$ and greater than $n$. Thus if we take $2^{2n} - {2n\choose n}$ we have exactly twice the number of combinations of size greater than $n$. This gives us our final answer as
$$
\frac{2^{2n} - {2n\choose n}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You would have to subtract $\binom{2n}{n}$ from $2^{2n}$ and then divide by $2$.

Comment: why would you divide by 2?

Comment: @TheUsualProcess see my comment, which follows your query.